# Online personal extension collection of Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Is it possible to have an online site to see the list/collection of installed extensions of the Chrome browsers installed among my PCs?

ps.

I noticed that we have the Chrome backup feature which will restore my chrome extensions after we sign in via a Google account.

So I need to see the list online somewhere so that to disabled/remove the extensions that I don't wanna waste time reinstalling.

Comment: doesn't `chrome://chrome/extensions/` show that?

Comment: @Sathya It does show but that is just the local machine i.e. it won't be available for me on another PC

Comment: ... that's what you're asking for --> _Is it possible to place to see the list/collection of installed extensions of the browser on my PC_

Comment: @Sathya Thank you. I have clearify my question.

Answer (score 2):

If you sign into Chrome with your Google account it can sync your installed extensions on all of the machines you use Chrome.

You can control this by going to Settings -> Advanced sync settings...

[image: Sync settings]